# How to find whether an attribute is available in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to find whether an attribute is available anywhere in the XML using XSL. For example in the below xml I need to check whether the Manager attribute exist anywhere. If exists I need to generate a CSV output with EmployeeID, Name & Manager columns otherwise just EmployeeID & Name columns.

```
<Root>
  <Metadata>
   <id>A001</id>
   <name>Test</name>
  </Metadata>
  <Employers>
    <Employer>
      <Employee id="aaa"><Name>Rick</Name></Employee>
      <Employee id="bbb"><Name>Ram</Name></Employee>
    </Employer>
    <Employer Manager="True">
      <Employee id="ddd"><Name>Bob</Name></Employee>
      <Employee id="dcc"><Name>Tan</Name></Employee>
    </Employer>
    <Employer>
      <Employee id="fff"><Name>Zak</Name></Employee>
      <Employee id="vvv"><Name>sha</Name></Employee>
    </Employer>
  </Employers>
</Root>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
//@Manager
```

Or, if the `Manager` attribute must contain the string `True`:

```
//@Manager[.='True']
```

`//` is an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. So `//@Manager` returns every `Manager` attribute in the document. Iterating all nodes in a document is expensive, so it's a good idea to use a global variable which tells whether there is a `Manager` attribute:

```
<xsl:variable name="has-manager-attr" select="boolean(//@Manager)"/>
```

I used the `boolean` function since we're only interested in whether a `Manager` attribute exists. Then you can test that variable in the template that creates the CSV lines:

```
<!-- add name and id columns -->
<xsl:if test="$has-manager-attr">
    <!-- add manager column -->
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="someElement/@someAttrName">
<!-- DO BLOCK -->
</xsl:template>
```